# Recursion Stack Trace explanation using javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

```js
// Recursive javascript program for level
// order traversal of Binary Tree

// Class containing left and right child of current
// node and key value
class Node {
  constructor(val) {
    this.data = val;
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
  }
}


// Root of the Binary Tree
var root = null;

// Function to print level order traversal of tree
function printLevelOrder() {
  var h = height(root);
  var i;
  // for (i = 1; i <= h; i++)
  printCurrentLevel(root, h);
}

// Compute the "height" of a tree -- the number
// of nodes along the longest path
// from the root node down to the farthest leaf node.
function height(root) {
  if (root == null)
    return 0;
  else {
    // Compute height of each subtree
    var lheight = height(root.left);
    var rheight = height(root.right);

    // Use the larger one
    if (lheight > rheight)
      return (lheight + 1);
    else
      return (rheight + 1);
  }
}

// Print nodes at the current level
function printCurrentLevel(root, level) {

  //  alert("root data = "+root.data+" : level = "+level);


  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML + "<br/>" + "root data = " + root.data + " : level = " + level + "";



  if (root == null)
    return;
  if (level == 1) {
    //alert(root.data);

  } else if (level > 1) {

    printCurrentLevel(root.left, level - 1);
    printCurrentLevel(root.right, level - 1);
  }
}

// Driver program to test above functions

root = new Node(1);
root.left = new Node(2);
root.right = new Node(3);
root.left.left = new Node(4);
root.left.right = new Node(5);
root.right.left = new Node(6);
root.right.right = new Node(7);

root.left.left.left = new Node(8);
root.left.left.right = new Node(9);



console.log("Level order traversal of  binary tree is ");
printLevelOrder();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <h2>My First JavaScript</h2>


  <p id="demo"></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Why is the output for the above code is

```
root data = 1 : level = 4
root data = 2 : level = 3
root data = 4 : level = 2
root data = 8 : level = 1
root data = 9 : level = 1
root data = 5 : level = 2
```

it did not print `root data = 3: level = 3` while using recursion

and if comment the code as below the output would be `root data = 1 : level = 4`

```
if (root == null)
       //   return ;
```

Please help me to understand this.

Reference:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/level-order-tree-traversal/

Comment: what result do you expect?

Comment: I expected it would print root data = 3: level = 3 aswell.

Comment: why has the root a level of depth? for me, it should have zero.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/level-order-tree-traversal/ taken reference from here

Comment: Commonly the *level* of a node is numbered with 1 being the root's level, 2 is used for the root's children. You seem to have an opposite number. Please clarify what exactly the total output is that you expect. Secondly, a level-order traversal means that you output the nodes from top (root) to bottom, and on a specific level, from left-to-right. Finally, recursion is not the right tool for level order traversal. Why did you choose that?

Comment: I am trying to understand the implementation of level order traversal from the website .... https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/level-order-tree-traversal/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that node 3 is not printed is because program runs into an error before getting there.

In this code:

```
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML + "<br/>" 
                                  + "root data = " + root.data + " : level = " + level + "";
  if (root == null)
    return;
```

...the first statement makes access to `root.data`, but it hasn't checked whether `root` might be `null`. That check comes too late. You shouldn't print anything when `root` happens to be `null`. So move the `if` guard *before* the "printing":

```
  if (root == null)
    return;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML + "<br/>" 
                                  + "root data = " + root.data + " : level = " + level + "";
```

Now the output will be:

```
root data = 1 : level = 4
root data = 2 : level = 3
root data = 4 : level = 2
root data = 8 : level = 1
root data = 9 : level = 1
root data = 5 : level = 2
root data = 3 : level = 3
root data = 6 : level = 2
root data = 7 : level = 2
```

#### Remarks

- Although you refer to "level order traversal", this is not a level order traversal. In a level order traversal, you would need to get the output in this order:

  ```
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
  ```

  Instead, your code has produced a *pre-order* traversal. Recursion is not the right mechanism for achieving a level-order traversal.
- Level numbering is not as you have used it. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)#Terminology) states: *"The level of a node is the number of edges along the unique path between it and the root node. This is the same as depth."* That means the root should not get level number 4, but number 0. And deeper nodes will have a greater level number, not less.
- The function `printCurrentLevel` doesn't really do what its name suggest: it prints *all* levels. It surely stops recurring when `level` is 1, but that would have happened anyway, because as you have numbered the levels, a node at level 1 has no children, so any recursive call would be made with `root` equal to `null`.
- Following the previous point, you shouldn't need to calculate the height of the tree to make a traversal.
- Even if you would use the concept of height, its common definition is the number of **edges* from root to the deepest leaf, so that means your height is one unit off: a leaf node has height 0, and so for `root == null` you should return -1.

### Level order

To implement level order, you typically use a queue instead of a stack, and so recursion is not the way to go.

Here is an implementation of a level order traversal, outputting to the console. It uses a generator function, which is quite suitable for this purpose:

```js
class Node {
  constructor(val) {
    this.data = val;
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
  }
}

// Generator function for level order traversal of tree
function* generateLevelOrder(root) {
    const queue = [root];
    for (const node of queue) {
        if (!node) continue;
        yield node.data;
        queue.push(node.left, node.right);
    }
}

// Driver program to test above functions

var root = new Node(1);
root.left = new Node(2);
root.right = new Node(3);
root.left.left = new Node(4);
root.left.right = new Node(5);
root.right.left = new Node(6);
root.right.right = new Node(7);
root.left.left.left = new Node(8);
root.left.left.right = new Node(9);

// Print level order:
for (const data of generateLevelOrder(root)) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: It make sense now... could you please clarify why is the output empty if i comment return statement empty   if (root == null)
    //return;

Comment: If you comment out `return`, then the next statement is made conditional to the `if` condition. This makes no sense.

Comment: what i meant was if(root == null) {  //return } ...But I have understood now...Thank you